# jquery accordion broken after partial ajax page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jquery accordion and it works fine on initial page load, but then I have some ajax commands that reload part of the page, essentially the inner body of the page.

When this happens, the accordion is broken, since the reload i do is just replacing the innerHTML of almost the entire body field.

The script that loads the accordion is also included in the replaced HTML, but obviously that doesn't help.

How can I keep (or reinvoke) the accordion effect after replacing the innerHTML of my entire page?

```
<div class="art-Post-inner" id="ajaxWrapper">
        <div id="accordion">
                <h3><a href="#">Skärm 1</a></h3>
                <div>
                    my accordion content
                </div>
        </div>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $( '#accordion' ).accordion({
                    collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight: false
                });
            });

        </script>
```

This is the art that gets replaced entirely by setting the innerHTML of the div with id=ajaxWrapper.

i trust you see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the jquery accordion function in the success callback of the `.ajax` request:

Example:

```
var accordionOpts = {
    collapsible: "true",
    active: "false",
    autoHeight: "false"
    };

$('#accordion').accordion(accordionOpts);

$("#replaceContent").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            html: "<div id='accordion'><h3><a href='#'>Skärm 2</a></h3><div>my accordion content</div></div>"
        },
        url: '/echo/html/',
        success: function(data) {
            $(".art-Post-inner").html(data);
            $('#accordion').accordion(accordionOpts);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Scgc/3/

Answer (score 4):

use  $( ".selector" ).accordion( "refresh" );

Comment: That actually worked. Why is everyone creating difficult scripts when it can be done in one line? Thank you very much

Comment: Solved my problem as well! more info: https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/